# spring boot Eureka microservice discovery and registration fails in docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, microservices

I created a eureka server microservice and a normal microservice , usually when I run both the service separately using STS tool service discovery and registration works fine , but whenever i tried to launch in docker that time registration fails.

## Code is below -

## Eureka Server

## application.properties

```
spring.application.name=eureka-service
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.instance.hostname=eureka-service
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty=0
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/SpringEureka-1.0.jar SpringEureka-1.0.jar
EXPOSE 8761
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","SpringEureka-1.0.jar"]
```

## Normal Microservice

## application.properties

```
server.port: 8010
spring.application.name=eureka-client
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry= true
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.proxy-host=localhost
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/HystrixTest-1.0.jar HystrixTest-1.0.jar
EXPOSE 8010
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","HystrixTest-1.0.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everything that you did is all right you just need to enable the ports using the 
`docker run -P 8761:8761 <your_docker_image>` command.
And change also the configuration from `eureka.instance.hostname=eureka-service` to `eureka.instance.hostname=localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Are you link the HystrixTest container to Eureka Server container?

You can get more detail in here: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

The better question if you post docker-compose file or your cmd when starting the container.

Comment: i created a docker file but still that issue not resolved